# Does protobuf net support object graphs of shared references inside list/arrays?

Tags: protobuf-net

It seems that protobuf net doesn't support AsReference for lists/array and also AsReference for objects inside list/array. Will this be supported in final v2?

```
[ProtoMember(1, AsReference=true, DynamicType=true)]
List<object> list;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can ignore it, it works. I have debug sources of v2 and it is just an assert on ValueMember.cs:ln258 Helpers.DebugAssert(itemType == ser.ExpectedType, "Wrong type in the tail");

Answer (score 2):

At current, no and no - but I should; collections are a gap here currently. One I shall address soon.