# protobuf-net arrays of complex types with inheritance 

Tags: protobuf-net

I have an hierarchy, lets say BaseClass <- DerivedClass
I want to serialize a BaseClass[] array with mixed DerivedClass and BaseClass objects
I use V2 Sourcecode Revision r438 (Aug 9, 2011)

Pseudocode:
myArray = new BaseClass[] {new BaseClass(), new DerivedClass()};

I tried several declarations, but i don't get the desired result:

```
[ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
private BaseClass[] myArray;
```

-> Wont deserialize all references are not set

```
[ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
private object[] myArray;
```

-> deserailze, but array type changed from BaseClass[] to object[]

Any suggetions how i can get my original BaseClass[] array back?

[Edit] Unit Tests:

```
namespace TechnologyEvaluation.Protobuf.ArrayOfBaseClassTest
{
    using System;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using ProtoBuf;
    using ProtoBuf.Meta;

    [ProtoContract]
    class BaseClassArrayContainerClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public Base[] BaseArray { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class ObjectArrayContainerClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public object[] ObjectArray { get; set; }

    }
    [ProtoContract]
    class Base
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string BaseClassText { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class Derived: Base
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string DerivedClassText { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class ArrayOfBaseClassTests : AssertionHelper
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestObjectArrayContainerClass()
        {
            var model = CreateModel();
            var container = new ObjectArrayContainerClass();
            container.ObjectArray = this.CreateArray();
            var cloned = (ObjectArrayContainerClass) model.DeepClone(container);
            Expect(cloned.ObjectArray, Is.Not.Null);

            foreach (var obj in cloned.ObjectArray )
            {
                Expect(obj as Base, Is.Not.Null);
            }

            Expect(cloned.ObjectArray[1] as Derived, Is.Not.Null);
            Expect(cloned.ObjectArray.GetType(), Is.EqualTo(typeof(Base[])));

        }

        [Test]
        public void TestBaseClassArrayContainerClass()
        {
            var model = CreateModel();
            var container = new BaseClassArrayContainerClass();
            container.BaseArray = this.CreateArray();
            var cloned = (BaseClassArrayContainerClass) model.DeepClone(container);
            Expect(cloned.BaseArray, Is.Not.Null);

            foreach (var obj in cloned.BaseArray)
            {
                Expect(obj as Base, Is.Not.Null);
            }
            Expect(cloned.BaseArray[1] as Derived, Is.Not.Null);
            Expect(cloned.BaseArray.GetType(), Is.EqualTo(typeof(Base[])));
        }

        RuntimeTypeModel CreateModel()
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

            model.Add(typeof(ObjectArrayContainerClass), true);
            model.Add(typeof(BaseClassArrayContainerClass), true);
            model.Add(typeof(Base), true);
            model[typeof(Base)].AddSubType(100, typeof(Derived));

            return model;
        }

        Base[] CreateArray()
        {
            return new Base[] { new Base() { BaseClassText = "BaseClassText" }, new Derived() { BaseClassText = "BaseClassText", DerivedClassText = "DerivedClassText" } };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012313/does-protobuf-net-support-object-graphs-of-shared-references-inside-list-arrays - short version - the behaviour inside lists / arrays still needs a little love. I was actually planning to try to look at that this evening.

Comment: Hi Marc, i have red this before. Array serialization works but changes the array type on deserialization to object[]. At the moment i copy this array into a correct array BaseClass[] after deserialization and reassign it to the field. should i send you a code sample?

Comment: By all means - then I'll have a concrete sample to add to the unit tests, so it *stays* working; see my profile for e-mail. About to head out, but should be able to look later.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this; *currently*, very little is encoded about the list itself. I have plans to address this (including both type and as-reference), but it is going to take a little work.